# Possible to make Visual Studio only show a list of files which didn't compile?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

A low-level code change I've made means lots of files no longer compile. It's easy to fix each such file, but each generates a whole stack of compile errors which makes it a bit hard to see which files are affected.

Can I easily generate from within VC++ 2008 a list only of the names of each file which failed to compile, without the errors themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that I can suggest is to use the Error List window.

It can filter out warnings and other messages (only leaving the errors), and then sort the resulting list by filename. The same file will appear multiple times however, which is not what you want.

Should you be really motivated, you can probably write a VSPackage to display the files only once, but that's a lot of work for (what I consider to be) little gain.